# 'panic!' while using Json object and iterating through string values

Tags: rust

I am trying to find values inside a JSON file (output.json) Using keys that are given in a text file (keys.txt).

I loaded keys.txt and used strip(",") to create an iterable. I have converted the output.json file into 'output_data' variable as type rustc_serialize::json::Json by using Json::from_str().

```
let output_json = process_file(&output);
let mut keys_values = process_keys(&keys)

let mut split = keys_values.split(",");

for s in split {
   println!("{}",output_json[s])
}
```

the query, output_data["name"] provides the corresponding value. But, Panics when given the &str value I got from the iterable using strip().

Comment: please read [ask], [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `rustc_serialize` has been deprecated for several years. Unless you have a very good reason to still be using it, I'd recommend switching to [`serde`](https://serde.rs/).

Comment: Also, does the key you're searching for actually exist? Generally if you index into a collection in Rust, panicking is the expected outcome if the index does not exist. Collections will usually provide a `get` method which returns an `Option`, for the cases where you're not sure if the thing you're looking for is there.